# Windows7 x64 clipboard failure

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, citrix

I'm using windows 7 x64 and i need to work with citrix client.
Unfortunately my clipboard stops working after 5-10 minutes with citrix apps.
I can't copy/paste anything. But on citrix clipboard is still working.

Problem disappears after rebooting computer. But it's takes too much time.
Is there any way to restart clipboard process or fix this problem without rebooting ?

Thanks !

**UPD.1**
Copy/Paste is broken only on my local computer. It means that when I'm pressing ctrl+c (also when doing the same with mouse) ctrl+v pastes nothing (in GUI menu it's highlighted with gray - disabled).
Occasionally it repairs itself when I'm starting rebooting: nsd.exe crashes with some exception, reboot stops and then it works again. But I'm still not sure that problem is in nsd.exe (Lotus notes)

Comment: What have you tried doing to fix this yourself? Also, "stops working" isn't really clear enough to be of any use. For instance, is copy/paste broken in the host computer only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing happens to me when running windows xp and a ton of other applications that I use for work, but it goes away after closing some applications. It appears to be some sort of memory issue. Have you tried to close a few applications and trying to see if copy/paste comes back to life?

Comment: In my case it was Firefox. After closing it - clipboard worked again.

Comment: I had the same problem when connecting to my Virtual Box, unfortunately Virtual Box was the culprit using too much memory.